# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified targetSdkVersion31

Tags: android, android-studio

the android:exported="true" existe in the AndroidManifest.xml file but always i have the same problem

Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. AndroidV2.app main manifest (this file)

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bfi.bsic.togo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.FrontOfficeMobileApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.app.activity.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.NitaWithdrawActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.NitaReloadActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ContributionSunuHistoryActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ContributionSunuActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GimCardEnrollmentActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GimacRecivedRemitanceActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GTPCardTransferActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GTPCardDepositActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PrepaidCardMovementsActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PrepaidCardBalanceActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CardEnrollmentActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SonabelPrePayActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ExpressoB2WActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SonabelHistoryActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SonabelActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.WithdrawWithoutCardActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GimacQRPaymentActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GimacTransferActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.GimacActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MtnGNWithdrawActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MtnGNReloadActivity"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MoovTogoW2BActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MoovTogoB2WActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MoovActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.DgiHistoryActiviy"
             />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.AddBeneficiaryActivity"
             />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.DgiActiviy"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.OribaReloadHistoryActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.OribaReloadActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.MtnReloadActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.MtnWithdrawActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.CnamDuplicateActiviy"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.CnamHistoryActiviy"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.CnamActiviy"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.CnpsHistoryActiviy"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.ConsultationTaxesPaidActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.PayingTaxesActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.WalletMobileMoneyActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.TransferPermanentActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.PrepaidCardWithdrawActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.MobileMoneyActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.PrepaidCardDepositActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.ReceivedMultipleDirectDebitActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.ContributionHistoryActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.HistoryContributionActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.TransactionConsultationActivity"
            />
        <activity   android:name=".activity.CheckBookBankRequestActivity"
            />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.app.activity.SelectAppActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.app.activity.activity.SelectLanguageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" /> <!-- Mobile Banking Activities -->
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CreateNewMessagingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_messanging"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MultipleDirectDebitActivity"
            android:label="@string/prepaid_card_withdraw"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ContributionActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.Cnps_Activiy"
            android:label="@string/cnps"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ColowsoWithdrawActivity"
            android:label="@string/withdraCard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ColowsoDepositActivity"
            android:label="@string/depositCard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PunctualTransactionActivity"
            android:label="@string/transactions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ChatMessagingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MessagingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TermDepositActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_term_deposit"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CheckBankAcivity"
            android:label="@string/checkBank"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CheckNewBankAcivity"
            android:label="@string/checkBank"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.HomeSlidesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LoanActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PaymentsPlanActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_plan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PinCodeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PDFViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.E_Document_Activity"
            android:label="E_Documents"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.E_All_Document_Activity"
            android:label="E_Documents"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SetTermeDeposit"
            android:label="@string/termedeposit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TombeAnticipeActivity"
            android:label="@string/tombeanticipe"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.Request_Disposition_Activity"
            android:label="@string/disposition"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />

        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.Subscribe3_Activity"
            android:label="Inscription"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.Subscribe4_Activity"
            android:label="Inscription"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.Subscribe2_Activity"
            android:label="Inscription"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SubscribeActivity"
            android:label="Inscription"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.RelationInActivity1"
            android:label="@string/relation_in"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.RelationInActivity2"
            android:label="@string/relation_in"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.RelationInActivity3"
            android:label="@string/relation_in"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CreditRequestConsultActivity"
            android:label="@string/list_request_credit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CreditRequestInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/modify_request_credit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CashWithdrawalActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_cash_withdrawal"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CreditRequestTrackActivity"
            android:label="@string/state_credit_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.WesternUnionActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_western_union"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TransactionActivityInternational"
            android:label="@string/transferInternational"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CertifiedAccountStatementActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_certified_account_statement"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PrepaidCardActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_prepaid_card"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MobileCreditActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_bgfi_mobile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.BgfiExpressActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_fast_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CurrencyExchangeActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_currency_exchange"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SendMoneyActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_money_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.BankInsuranceActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_bank_insurance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CheckRemittanceActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_check_remitance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.AddCheckActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_check_attach"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.BearerCheckActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_bearer_check_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SuggestionAndComplaintActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_complaint"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SendMoneyExternalActivity"
            android:label="@string/money_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SendMoneyMobileMoneyActivity"
            android:label="@string/mobile_money_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SendMoneyExternalHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/consult_money_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LockCheckExternalActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_lock_checkbook_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ChatKitActivity"
            android:label="@string/chat_kit_activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PermanentSendMoneyExternalHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/history_permanent_money_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PermanentSendMoneyExternalActivity"
            android:label="@string/permanent_money_transfer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.BeneficiaryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LockCardActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_lock_card"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.MouvementsActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_statements_heading"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.NextMovementActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_next_statements_heading"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CashDepositActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_cash_deposit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CheckBookRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_checkbook_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LockCheckActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_lock_check"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LockCardCallCenterActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_lock_card"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.NotificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_notification"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PrintTicketActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TicketNumberActivity"
            android:label="@string/ticket"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CardRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_card_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TrackCardRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_track_card_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TrackRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_track_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".fingerprint.FingerprintActivity"
            android:label="Fingerprint"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TrackCheckBookRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_track_check_book_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ListCardActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_card_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.AppointmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_appointment_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SuggestionActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_suggestion_request"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.PasswordManagmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_manage_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.IncreaseCreditCardCeilingActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_increase_credit_card_ceiling"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.LoadingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loading"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ConnectedDevicesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" /> <!-- Mobile Money Activities -->
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.PasswordManagmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_manage_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.PinCodeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDialog" /> <!-- android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog" -->
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.SubscribeActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_subscribe"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.WhitePinCodeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
        <activity 
            android:name="com.bfi.bsic.mobilemoney.activity.QrCodeScannerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.QrCodeScannerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.TransactionActivity"
            android:label="@string/transfer"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CardActivity"
            android:label="@string/card"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CreditRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/Credit"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.CheckActivity"
            android:label="@string/checkk"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ContactActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.HistoryAllTransactionNational"
            android:label="@string/consult_money_transfer"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.BalanceAndMovementsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[merged manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE9k3.png)

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

**Downgrade targetSdkVersion31 to 30 or 29** and see if it helps

Comment: Play store requires version 31 for deployment